# Calling non-generic method from generic method

Tags: java, generics

I have some non-generic method for overloaded for specific Objects
EX:

```
protected boolean internalAdd(IP4BlockObject block) {...}
protected boolean internalAdd(IP4NetworkObject network) {...}
```

I want to write one method like

```
protected <T extends AbstractEntityObject>boolean internalAdd(T t) {}
```

and from this method can i call non-generic method (Without using instanceof operator ;) )

Comment: What are you trying to do ? the question is not really clear.

Comment: So you want a generic method that magically understands which specific method to call?

Comment: I think, if I understand the rather vague question correctly, the answer is no.  If you are going to handle all of the various objects that might get passed in, your method would still have to know what type it received if there is only going to be one handler for all types.

Comment: I am creating one generic method, in this method i want to use internalAdd(), this is non-generic method so i want to create a new overloaded generic method of  internalAdd, which will internally call existing method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that will be compile time error.

> The method internalAdd(IP4BlockObject) in the type  is not applicable for the arguments (T)

Because your methods of type:

```
protected boolean internalAdd(IP4BlockObject block) {...}
protected boolean internalAdd(IP4NetworkObject network) {...}
```

And for `protected <T extends AbstractEntityObject>boolean internalAdd(T t) {}` you will get `t` as type of T . So if you call:

```
internalAdd(t);
```

this will give you compile time error because `internalAdd()` only expect `IP4BlockObject` or `IP4NetworkObject`.

**Note:** If all these method is on same class then `internalAdd(t);` will call your generic method again, so you will end up with endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `IP4BlockObject` and `IP4NetworkObject` extends `AbstractEntityObject` and you want to dispatch between some overloaded methods using abstract reference?
I so, I don't really understand purpose of using generic method for this. Why don't you declare this method that way:

```
boolean internalAdd(AbstractEntityObject object) {}
```

Then you need to choose desired method for given object. There are not straight forward way to do this without using `instance of` operator, or some polymorphic method giving type of derived class, eg. as `enum`.

If you want to run away from this, you can rewrite code and allow derived classes to choose desired method by themselves, by calling theirs polymorphic method with some interface. But is it really worth it?